# How to send a silent message with discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am having trouble figuring out how to send a message silently using discord.js as all my previous attempts have failed and I couldn't find any documentation online about sending silent messages with bots.

I have tried

```
var msg = await channel.send("@silent message");
```

which results in
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWmP0.png)
along with

```
var msg = await channel.send({
  content: "message",
  silent: true,
  is_silent: true,
  ephemeral: true
});
```

which results in
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpQqu.png)

I even looked through the `MessageFlagsBitField` enum and I did not find anything indicating a silent message.

Comment: What do you expect a silent message to do? [From my research](https://www.reddit.com/r/Discord_/comments/10xak99/silent_messages/), they don't send a notification or sound, but still trigger the unread/mentions indicator. Is that what you're wanting?

Comment: I don't believe silent messages are available in the api, so discordjs wouldn't have an implementation for it. If your goal is to mention a member without sending them a notification as Samathingamajig, put it inside an embed.

Comment: Please explain what do you mean by slient messages

Comment: By silent message, I mean one without a notification, as a Discord user you can usually make a silent message by typing '@silent' at the beginning of your message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured it out.

After console logging sent [silent messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caLB6.png) and comparing them to [regular messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCln2.png) I noticed that silent messages had `flags: MessageFlagsBitField { bitfield: 4096 }` while regular messages had `flags: MessageFlagsBitField { bitfield: 0 }`

After a bit of messing with the code I ended up with:

```
var msg = await channel.send({
  content: "message",
  flags: [ 4096 ]
});
```

which actually results in [a silent message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/To5tS.png)!

Though I did manage to find a solution, I still wonder if there is a more official way of doing this.